# Flex: How to show the item index in my item renderer

Tags: apache-flex

How to show the item index in my item renderer.Owner of the item renderer is TileList. 
http://www.swsd.k12.pa.us/baresvle/mathmaterials/numbers/number_grid.jpg

Comment: What index do you want to display?  The index of your data in the dataProvider?  The index of the row taht the itemRenderer is in?  OR the index of the column that the itemRenderer is in?

Comment: I want to show The index of the row/column that the itemRenderer is in? Like a Number Grid http://www.swsd.k12.pa.us/baresvle/mathmaterials/numbers/number_grid.jpg

Comment: That's a tricky request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is try something like this in your itemRenderer:

```
var index: int = ((listData.owner as TileList).dataProvider as ListCollectionView).getItemIndex())
```

More info on [listData.owner](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/BaseListData.html#owner) and the [listCollectionView.getItemIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#getItemIndex%28%29) method.

Comment: Works perfect String((myOwner.dataProvider as ListCollectionView).getItemIndex(data));
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946465/flex-datagrid-with-row-number-column/2527795#2527795

Answer (score 0):

```
private var handleDataChangedEnabled:Boolean = false;

private var myOwner : TileList;

override public function set data(value:Object):void 
{ 
 super.data = value;

 myOwner = owner as TileList; 

 if (!handleDataChangedEnabled) {
    addEventListener("dataChange", handleDataChanged);
  }
}

public function handleDataChanged(event:Event):void {

 this.gridValue.text = String((myOwner.dataProvider as ListCollectionView).getItemIndex(data));
}
```

Add this code to your tileList item renderer , add Label(id gridValue) to display the Grid number.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in ItemRenderer called itemIndex. It's as simple as that!