# Flex <s:List> Itemrender Index

Tags: flash, apache-flex, indexing, adobe, itemrenderer

Is there a way within a `<s:List>` item renderer in Flex (4.6) to identify the index of a particular item in the list, within the item renderer itself?

I tried using the `itemIndex` property of the class, but it always returned zero. Also, [this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263253/flex-how-to-show-the-item-index-in-my-item-renderer) gave me several runtime errors.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that `itemIndex` wasn't working because its value yet hadn't been set during the life cycle of the list's creation.

Within the item renderer I was listening for an `addedToStage` event and used `itemIndex` within its handler. Once I changed the `addedToStage` event to `creationComplete`, `itemIndex` then had the proper value.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Main application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:List itemRenderer="IndexedItemRenderer">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Item A</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item B</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item C</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item D</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item E</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
</s:Application>
```

IndexedItemRenderer item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    autoDrawBackground="true">
    <s:Label text="{itemIndex + 1}. {data}"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just figured out why `itemIndex` wasn't returning a proper value. I posted my answer above.

Comment: If feasible, use data binding in item renderer. I have just updated my item renderer to use itemIndex you mentioned as a better option comparing to my 1st attempt.

Comment: I would use data binding, except that the index is used in a calculation that is performed on each item in the list.